# Eclipse Plug-In Dependencies Vanished

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing OSGi in Eclipse, and the plugin dependices has vanished for a project.

I have checked .classpath, and it seems fine:

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

I have tried starting eclipse with -clean and I have tried creating a new workspace and importing the projects into that workspace - no luck with either.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Also, if I try to re-add the plugin dependencies within the build path, the resolved classpath list is empty in the dialog.

Comment: Do you have the Eclipse SDK feature installed?

Comment: What does your plugin.xml look like? That's really where the plugin dependencies live.

Comment: Turns out by doing a null edit and save to the MANIFEST.MF file, the dependencies reappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Some strange eclipse bug. Re-edited the manifest file, and the dependencies reappeared and the project successfully compiled.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone still encounters this issue, the solution that worked for me eventually was (on Eclipse 4.3)

1. Delete the org.eclipse.pde.core.prefs file under the .settings folder in the plugin project
2. Remove/Delete the project from the workspace
3. Re-import the project back into the workspace

This should fix the Plug-in Dependencies entries for that project.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Something similar worked for me - I had this problem with Eclipse Mars and had to delete all of the project metadata I could find, then re-pull the project from my git repo and re-import it.

Answer (score 3):

Check that you defined a valid target platform in Eclipse.

Go to Window -> Preferences -> Plug-in Development -> Target Platform.

When importing the plugin it was set to an empty target platform, you can verify this by first edit the selected target, then selecting the content tab of the target platform, it's empty.

I changed the Target Platform to 'Running Platform (Active)'. 
This imported the necessary libs in the project, they were added to the plugin dependencies.

You can also opt to define your own custom target platform but that needs some more work and knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The .classpath file is for Java builder only. Dependencies are in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF